# Android Development: Button- findViewById?

Tags: java, android, button, android-button

What is the intent behind this piece of code?

```
Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
```

Comment: Did I answer your question completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML files, you create IDs for the widgets you put on the screen.

In that code, you are creating a button reference (`sButton`) to be the button corresponding to the ID of `button_1`

`findViewById` searches for a button based on its ID - the ID is located in the `R.java` file of your project: `Project Folder > gen > package > R.java`

The `R.java` file holds references to everything (or basically everything?) in your project. It's an essential part of it.

That is why the parameter of `findViewById` is `R.id.button_1` because you are searching for the ID of `button_1` in the `R` class (it's a  static field).

You are then casting that ID of the `button_1` to a button with the `(Button)` in front of the `findViewById`.

---

Extra note:

If you look at the `R.java` class, you have it declared as: `public final class R {` so that's where the `R` in `R.id.button_1` comes from.

Then you have another inner class like this: `public static final class id {` so that's where the `id` comes from in `R.id.button_1`

Then, in the `id` inner class, you have this (amoung other things): 
`public static final int button_1=...;` where the `...` would be some code to represent the `int` value. That's where the `button_1` comes from in `R.id.button_1`

So bascially, `R.id.button_1` goes to the `R` class, then the `id` inner class, then accesses the actual `int` value of the `id` name.

Comment: This has been very useful, I believe that generally you dont need to alter R.java class? Also, is it necessary to cast to a button? I am only new to android development (2 weeks), would the android developer site be the best resource to being learning? Many thanks

Comment: @RNI2013 *Never* alter the `R.java` class - when you create things, it does that for you. And Yes it is, because `findViewById(...)` returns a `View` which could also be a TextView, EditText, etc. And yes, the Android documentation is really well done.

Answer (score 1):

it finds a view in the associated layout XML by it's id, and casts it to a `Button`. Was it what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

Its used to find a Button which you have created in XML and bring it into the Java code so you can work with it. If you didnt do this you would not be able to give the button anything to do.